# Images in PySimpleGUI Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

So I am making a mail service application for a project with PySimpleGUI and I am really struggling with the image placement... here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


sg.theme('Dark')
layout = [[sg.Frame('', [[
        sg.Image('xmail.png', size=(1100, 300))]])],
            [sg.Frame('Options', [[
                sg.Checkbox('Confidential'), sg.Checkbox('Extra Confidential'),
                sg.Checkbox('Not Confidential')]])],
            [sg.Text('Sender Email'+':', size=(14, None)), sg.InputText(key='sender_email1')],
            [sg.Text('Sender Password'+':', size=(14, None)), sg.InputText(password_char='*', key='sender_password1')],
            [sg.Frame('Encryption key - (optional)', [[
                sg.Slider(range=(1, 100), orientation='v', size=(5, 20), default_value=25, key='slider_encrypt1'),
                sg.Slider(range=(1, 100), orientation='v', size=(5, 20), default_value=75, key='slider_encrypt2'),
                sg.Slider(range=(1, 100), orientation='v', size=(5, 20), default_value=55, key='slider_encrypt3')]])],
            [sg.Text('Receiver Email'+':', size=(14, None)), sg.InputText(key='receiver_email1')],
            [sg.Text('Subject', size=(14, None)), sg.InputText(key='subject1')],
            [sg.Multiline('Email...', key='email_message1', size=(70, 12))],
            [sg.Button('Send Mail', button_color=('white', 'green')),
            sg.Button('Cancel', button_color=('white', 'red'))]]


window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, size=(1100, 950))
event, values = window.read()
```

This is only the layout I have a lot of code under it for the actual function of the mail service. This is what it looks like -  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPKG2.png)

You can see the first image fits perfectly. What I want is to add an image on the right hand side which is vertical and would fit perfectly, but instead what happens is...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQdZv.png)

As you can see it completely messes it up and puts the text boxes out of order, does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I tried adding the code for the image containing the text into different positions but it never works, it always does the same, messes it all up :/

Thank you to everyone who reads this! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sg.Frame` or `sg.Column` to seperate left frame and right frame. Layout of left frame for your `Checkbox`, `Text`, `Slider`, `Multiline`, ..., and another layout of right frame for your another vertial image. Something like this

```py
top_frame = [[sg.Image(...)]]
left_frame = [[sg.Frame(...)], [sg.Text(...}], ...]
right_frame = [[sg.Image(...)]]

layout = [
    [sg.frame("", top_frame)],
    [sg.frame("", left_frame), sg.frame("", right_frame)]
]
```